# Crash when accessing a change

Tags: bug, documentation

When you try to access https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/29675 it causes the app to crash.

Comment: Yes this affects me too.

Comment: That gives me "Oops something bad happened" (but I'm using the desktop version).